# How to print the output in the application itself in Kivy, instead of printing it in console?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create a fairly simple and efficient port scanner with Python which has a GUI.

I've watched tutorials about how to write Python GUI apps with Tkinter and Kivy and so far I've written my code based on those tutorials

This is my `.py` file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import socket
import threading
import time


Builder.load_file(r"DemoPortScanner.kv")

def port_scan(port):
    for port in range(port_start, port_end):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            conn = sock.connect_ex((target_ip, port))
            if conn == 0:
                def printer(self):
                    i = 0
                    while self.is_printing:
                        self.root_widget.ids.result.text += f'Port {port}' + 'is Open!' + '\n'
                        i += 1
                    time.sleep(1)

                def do_print(self):
                    if not self.is_printing:
                        self.is_printing = True
                        self.print_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.printer)
                        self.print_thread.start()
                    else:
                        self.is_printing = False
                        self.print_thread.join()
                        self.print_thread = None
            else:
                pass

        except:
            print("Connection couldn't be made")

class MyLayout(Widget):
    def start_scan(self):

        global target
        target = self.ids.target_url.text
        target = str(target)

        global target_ip
        target_ip = socket.gethostbyname(target)
        print(target_ip)

        global port_start
        port_start = self.ids.port_start.text
        port_start = int(port_start)
        print(port_start)
        
        global port_end
        port_end = self.ids.port_end.text
        port_end = int(port_end)
        print(port_end)
        self.ids.result.text = ""

        port_scan(self)

class DemoPortScannerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoPortScannerApp().run()
```

and this is my `.kv` file:

```
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            rows: 1

            TextInput:
                id: target_url
                text: "www.python.org"
                halign: "center"
                font_size: 28
                size_hint: (1, 1)
                multiline : False

            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                rows: 2
                
                TextInput: 
                    id: port_start
                    text: '1'
                    halign: "left"
                    font_size: 28
                    size_hint: (1,1)
                    multiline: False
                
                TextInput:
                    id: port_end
                    text: "500"
                    halign: "left"
                    font_size: 28
                    size_hint: (1,1)
                    multiline: False
            
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                Button:
                    text: "Start Scan"
                    size_hint: (1,1)
                    font_size: 28
                    on_press: root.start_scan()

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 1

            TextInput:
                id: result
                text: "Open ports will be shown in here"
                halign: "center"
                font_size: 28
                size_hint: (1, 1)
                multiline : True
```

How can I display the output (Open ports) in the application itself?

I was able to print it in console, but when it comes to displaying it the application, whether via a TextInput or with a Label, I was nowhere near it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to declare your classes in both the .py and .kv or your code will not work. E.g in file1.py

   ```
    class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
       pass
   ```

   in file1.kv

   ```
    <MyLayout>:
        id: mylayout

        name: 'mylayout'
   ```

   etc.

2. You have `port_scan` as a global method, but you have not called it anywhere during the `MyApp.run()` process, so it won't call.

   Change the process and do this:

   ```
    class port_scan(Widget):
       pass # add code here
   ```

3. then add the widget to the layout in e.g. in `file1.kv`

   ```
    <MyLayout>:
        id: mylayout

        name: 'mylayout'

        MyWidget:
   ```